# how to know when singular solution satisfy initial condition?

Tags: linear-algebra

solve the ODE:
$\frac{dy}{dx}$− 2y=1 ,  y(1)=1

I found the y= $\frac{1}{2}$(3$e^{2(x-1)}$-1) where the singular sol is when 1+2y=0
but the answer says the singular solution does not satisfy the initial condition. A bit of background info I don't really understand what singular solutions. So can someone please explain?

Comment: The claimed singular solution is $y(x)=-\frac{1}{2}$ which doesn't satisfy y(1)=1.